# Why is $K$ a subobject of $B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

The question comes from Mitchell’s book “Theory of Categories”, Theorem 20.1 of chapter I.

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a category with pushouts, pullbacks and is normal and conormal. Then he has proved that $\mathscr{C}$ has finite products, finite coproducts, equalizers, and coequalizers. So $\mathscr{C}$ is exact. For all $A, B \in \mathscr{C}$ the morphisms $1_A, 1_B, 0$ induce
$$
  \delta \colon A \oplus B \longrightarrow A \times B
$$
Then he wants to prove that $\delta$ is an isomorphism. There is an exact sequence:
$$
  0 \longrightarrow K \longrightarrow A \oplus B \xrightarrow{\enspace\delta\enspace} A \times B \longrightarrow K' \longrightarrow 0  \tag{1}
$$
Then
$$
  K \longrightarrow A \oplus B \longrightarrow A
  \quad:=\quad
  K \longrightarrow A\oplus B \longrightarrow A\times B \longrightarrow A = 0
$$
implies $K$ is a subobject of $B$ in $A \oplus B$.

Why is $K$ a subobject of $B$?
It is hard to prove this in an abstract category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point is that $B\xrightarrow{u_B} A\oplus B $ is the kernel of

$ A \oplus B \xrightarrow{p_A} A $.